# django factory boy factory with OneToOne relationship and related field

Tags: python, django, testing, factory-boy

I am using [Factory Boy](https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy) to create test factories for my django app. The model I am having an issue with is a very basic Account model which has a OneToOne relation to the django User auth model (using django < 1.5):

```
# models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='USD')
    balance = models.CharField(max_length="5", default='0.00')
```

Here are my factories:

```
# factories.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

import factory

from models import Account


class AccountFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = Account

    user = factory.SubFactory('app.factories.UserFactory')
    currency             = 'USD'
    balance              = '50.00'

class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = User

    username = 'bob'
    account = factory.RelatedFactory(AccountFactory)
```

So I am expecting the factory boy to create a related UserFactory whenever AccountFactory is invoked:

```
# tests.py 
from django.test import TestCase

from factories import AccountFactory

class AccountTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = AccountFactory()

    def test_factory_boy(self):
        print self.factory.id
```

When running the test however, it looks like multiple User models are being create, and I am seeing an integriy error:

```
IntegrityError: column username is not unique
```

The documentation does mention watching out for loops when dealing with circular imports, but I am not sure whether that is whats going on, nor how I would remedy it. [docs](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html?#circular-imports)

If anyone familiar with Factory Boy could chime in or provide some insight as to what may be causing this integrity error it would be much appreciated!

Comment: FYI, the error happens even if there is no `post_save` signal.

Comment: Your right, i've edited the code examples accordingly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe this is because you have a circular reference in your factory definitions.  Try removing the line `account = factory.RelatedFactory(AccountFactory)` from the `UserFactory` definition.  If you are always going to invoke the account creation through AccountFactory, then you shouldn't need this line.

Also, you may consider attaching a sequence to the name field, so that if you ever do need more than one account, it'll generate them automatically.

Change: `username = "bob"` to `username = factory.Sequence(lambda n : "bob {}".format(n))` and your users will be named "bob 1", "bob 2", etc.

Comment: Also, see this: http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#circular-imports.  They have two SubFactory in the docs, instead of a RelatedFactory and a SubFactory.  Maybe that's causing a problem?

Answer (score 2):

To pass result of calling `UserFactory` to `AccountFactory` you should use `factory_related_name` ([docs](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.RelatedFactory.factory_related_name))

Code above works next way:

- `AccountFactory` for instantiating needs `SubFactory(UserFactory)`.
- `UserFactory` instantiates User.
- `UserFactory` after instantiating calls `RelatedFactory(AccountFactory)`
- Recursion,.. that is broken due to unique username constraint (you probably want to generate usernames via [`FuzzyText`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fuzzy.html?highlight=Fuzzy#fuzzytext) or [`Sequence`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=Sequence#sequence))

So you need write `UserFactory` like this:

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    account = factory.RelatedFactory(AccountFactory, factory_related_name='user')
    username = factory.Sequence(lambda a: 'email%04d@somedomain.com' % a)
    # rest of code
```

But you can still experience issues with already written tests. Imagine you have in tests places like next:

```
user = UserFactory()
account = Account(user=user)
```

Then adding `RelatedFactory` will break tests. If you haven't lots of tests and contributors in your project, you could rewrite them. But if not, it is not an option. Here is how it could be handled:

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Params:
        generate_account = factory.Trait(
            account=factory.RelatedFactory(AccountFactory, factory_related_name='user')
        )
```

Then code above won't be broken, because default call of `UserFactory` won't instantiate `AccountFactory`. To instantiate user with account:

```
user_with_account = UserFactory(generate_account=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because you're still defining a circular reference. UserFactory refers to AccountFactory and vice versa...

Answer (score 0):

You can set `account=None` in your Subfactory, see the example here:
https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#example-django-s-profile

```
user = factory.SubFactory('app.factories.UserFactory', account=None)
```